# Dropbox Android, authentication process random : session.authenticationSuccessful() returns false

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a problem regarding the authentication process.
I am eveloping an application using dropbox on Android, everything is working fine when i use the application for the first time.
I am able to link the application with my dropbox account. I am saving the keys in the shared preference. every things works fine.

Yet from time to time, I  have to give my agreement again saying i  want to link my account with my application(even if I already did it). i have to go through the whole authentication process, and I have the dropbox web view...

This weird behaviour happens all the time, when I make a change in my code and reload it on my phone, I always have to got through the whole authentication process.
I don t understand why "session.authenticationSuccessful()" return false for no apparent reason and all the other time returns true.

thanks for your help

Comment: The Dropbox Android Core SDK doesn't handle token persistence for you, so it sounds like there may be an issue with your implementation of this. Is there anything that might be causing the token to get cleared from your SharedPreferences, or are you accidentally startAuthentication when you don't mean to?

Comment: No, this is a really weird bug. Because if i m using my application, make the connection then leave the application, and coming back to it, I won t have any problem... well most of the time. yet sometimessession.authenticationSuccessful()" return false even if i feed him with my token, and also every time i build my application from my eclipse it will fail, even if i still have the token in the shared pref.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the token? You should include in your onResume() method these lines:

```
// save server session
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Mandatory call to complete the auth
                session.finishAuthentication();
                if (!mIsLogged) setLogged(mDBApi.getSession().isLinked());

                // Store it locally in our app for later use
                String tokens = session.getOAuth2AccessToken();
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("DROPBOX_PREFS", 0);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString(APP_KEY, tokens);
                editor.commit();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.i("SERVICE", "Error authenticating", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                Log.i("Exception", errors.toString());
            }
```

This way, after having got authenticated the first time, the session token is saved so the next time you should do this somewhere in your code:

```
    AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session;

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("DROPBOX_PREFS", 0);
    String token = prefs.getString(APP_KEY, null);

    if (token != null) {
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, token);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        setLogged(mDBApi.getSession().isLinked());
    } else {
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
    }
```